# Disable clipping on label

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

how can i prevent a label (XF-Label) from being clipped at its bounds? I want the label to overflow. This is my xaml:

```
<StackLayout  BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
              HorizontalOptions="Start"
              IsClippedToBounds="False"
              WidthRequest="30">
    
        <Label Text="Hallo World"
               BackgroundColor="GreenYellow"
               LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
               MaxLines="1">
        </Label>
</StackLayout>
```

This produces the following:
[image]

Update sample code with more informations:
My complete TestPage looks like this. There are three scrollviews (Rows, Columns, Data) which i can scroll simultaneously (for example: scrolling rows will scroll data automatically verical (`DataScroll.ScrollToAsync(ColumnHeaderScroll.ScrollX, TRowHeaderScroll.ScrollY, false);`)). I need the Rows with Text "Row to overflow" to overflow in the LightPink ScrollView, because this is RowHeader which describe the three following rows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
             BackgroundColor="Brown"
             Padding="0"
             x:Class="xxx">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid ColumnSpacing="0"
              RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ScrollView Grid.Column="1"
                        x:Name="ColumnHeaderScroll"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                        Grid.Row="0">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                             BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                             HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                             VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                             Spacing="0">
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                    <Label Text="Col" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <ScrollView Grid.Column="0"
                        x:Name="RowHeaderScroll"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Orientation="Vertical"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                        Grid.Row="1">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                             BackgroundColor="LightGreen"
                             HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                             IsClippedToBounds="False"
                             Spacing="0">
                    <Label Text="Row to overflow"
                           LineBreakMode="NoWrap" />
                    <Label Text="Row" />
                    <Label Text="Row" />
                    <Label Text="Row" />
                    <Label Text="Row to overflow"
                           LineBreakMode="NoWrap" />
                    <Label Text="Row" />
                    <Label Text="Row" />
                    <Label Text="Row" />
                    <Label Text="Row to overflow"
                           LineBreakMode="NoWrap" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <ScrollView Grid.Column="1"
                        x:Name="DataScroll"
                        VerticalOptions="Fill"
                        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                        Orientation="Both"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                        Grid.Row="1">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                             BackgroundColor="LightPink"
                             Spacing="0">
                    <Label Text="" />
                    <Label Text="Data" />
                    <Label Text="Data" />
                    <Label Text="Data" />
                    <Label Text="" />
                    <Label Text="Data" />
                    <Label Text="Data" />
                    <Label Text="Data" />
                    <Label Text="" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Use GridView instead of StackLayout to overflow.

Comment: I think you mean Grid. GridView is android. I can set Column Width to Auto, but this only expands the LightBlue area. I need the label to display remaining charaters in the brown area.

Comment: Grid for both your two layouts on the screen, could you post some code about the right side layout please?

Comment: I updated the question with more details. Sorry, but now it's more complex ;)

Comment: Well, if you intend to achieve something like [DataGrid](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/datagrid/overview), could try those packages and that's a different question. And about your overflow label, may I ask if the rows in the first column are static or might change dynamically. Here is [a similar example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shawyunz/XampleUI/main/Assets/DribComp/demo2.gif) with fixed row, which can be scrolled vertically on the page and horizontally on the right.

Comment: (last comment..., as possible solutions for your labels might be different from how your page is designed) But a common way of dealing with a long label is just to wrap or trim it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Grid.ColumnSpan and Grid.RowSpan to set the children in Gird to achieve what you want, code like:

```
   <Grid RowDefinitions="50,50,50,50,50,50"
      ColumnDefinitions="50,50,50"
          RowSpacing="0"
          ColumnSpacing="0">
        <Label Text="Hall"
               FontSize="Large"
               Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
           BackgroundColor="Green"/>
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Brown"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                 Grid.RowSpan="5"/>
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.RowSpan="5"/>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know RowSpan or ColumnSpan but this didn't help. I updated the question with more context infos.

Comment: The label is in the stacklayout so the width is limited.